# Windows Phone 8: passing data from PHP page to windows phone 8 app

Tags: c#, php, mobile, windows-phone-8

I need to send some data from php page to windows phone 8(C#) and need to display it.

Here is my wp8 side Code :

```
   private void Track_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
      HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(attackUri);
      request.BeginGetResponse(Showtext, request);

   }
 } 
 void Showtext(IAsyncResult result)
{
   HttpWebRequest request = result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;
   if (request != null)
   {
      try
      {
         WebResponse response = request.EndGetResponse(result);
         var txt = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

         //to display data passed from PHP page
         MessageBox.Show(txt.Result);
      }
      catch (WebException e)
      {

      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly is your problem? Your approach generally looks fine. Of course the requested php-page has to echo the result you want to display in this case.

Comment: I get error with  MessageBox.Show(txt.Result) @malte

Comment: Error 1 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'Content' and no extension method 'Content' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) @malte

Comment: An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.@malte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure, where you got your `request.Content` from, but it does not seem to be WP8 native.

Try the following. This is how it always worked for me:

```
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://www.google.de"));
    request.BeginGetResponse(ShowText, request);

    private void ShowText(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result);

        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string content = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            Debug.WriteLine(content);
        }
    }
```

Comment: its working fine but now i got another problem how could i retrieve data separately.My PHP page echo two parameter as result and i need those data to be assigned to variable p1 and p2 separately.I hope you could help me. @malte

Comment: `private void Showtext(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result);

            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                double content = Convert.ToDouble(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
                Debug.WriteLine(content);
            }
        }`

Comment: How about echoing a JSON string PHP-side and parse that into an object of your choice? - If you need help with it, just post another question here on SO or start a search :)